# Unable to connect to the server: x509: cannot validate certificate for $LOAD_BALANCER

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to convert a single master setup to 3 HA master. Load balancer is configured to accept traffic at port 443 and one of its backend is the single master IP and its port 443. The connectivity between load balancer and the k8s nodes are verified.

It's working fine before when the server in my ~/.kube/config used the IP of the master node. But when I tried to change it to the dedicated load balancer DNS. It throws the x509 cannot validate certificate error. We are using digicert, do I need to put it somewhere in the kube-api server or kubelet?

I am using https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/ as guide

```
sudo kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint companykube.com:443 --kubernetes-version v1.21.2 --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 --cri-socket /run/containerd/containerd.sock  --upload-certs --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=companykube.com,singlemasterIp,2ndmasterIP,3rdmasterIP --apiserver-bind-port=443
```

Comment: unfortunately the load balancer given is not properly configured the traffic from frontend to backend is not flowing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the problem is in the load balancer side. The traffic is not going through from front-end to back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Here are such a lot steps and aspects to create multi-master and you described so few.

Usually multi-master(and always HA) contains 3 masters that have properly configured etcd.

Please check [Install and configure a multi-master Kubernetes cluster with kubeadm](https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/kubernetes/beginners/Install-and-configure-a-multi-master-Kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm.html) - I used that article to create multi-master cluster.

your steps:

- Installing the HAProxy load balancer
- Generating the TLS certificates and distributing them
- Creating the certificate for the Etcd cluster and distributing them
- Installing and configuring Etcd
- Initializing the master nodes
- Configuring kubectl on the client machine(kubeconfig you are asking for)
- Deploying the overlay network

And I highly recommend you check [Kubernetes High Availability: No Single Point of Failure](https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-high-availability-no-single-point-of-failure/) - its about HA in real life. Maybe you need HA instead of multi-master to ensure your cluster is always accessible?

Comment: I added more details at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/103680 "Cannot create certificate signing request" should be the main point of investigation for me i think